# Trying to add a column to my data set in R that calculates the % of 2 other columns

Tags: r

Basically, I am using a dataset looking at the 2017 UK election data and I am trying to add a new column for votes cast for right wing parties, so UKIP and Conservatives. the dataset is for each constituency and gives numerical values for all the votes cast. but i am having difficulty adding a new column.

```
# % Right wing ====

ew_ele$Right2017 <- ((ew_ele$"17CON"+ew_ele$"17UKIP") /
                      rowSums(ew_ele[,8, 11, drop=TRUE]))*100
```

`ew_ele` is the name of the dataset, and `17CON` and `17UKIP` are the names of the columns which contain the number of votes, they are in the 8th and 11th column respectively

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Put the 8 and 11 inside of the combine function, like `c(8, 11)`